# CPP include directories setup in azure devops

Tags: c++, azure-devops

I am trying to setup a build pipeline in azure devops. I have a cpp project. It needs a Framemaker FDKs to build. I have the FDK files on my local storage as well as on TFS. I want to link them in my pipeline so that they can be used while building and do not throw file not found errors.

Comment: This depends on the configuration of the project. If the files are added to the repository they should be copied when building the project. Maybe you have a gitignore or are not included in the solution. If you use Visual Studio you can right click on a file -> properties and set "Copy always". When locally building do the files show up in the bin folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Framemaker FDK is installed on local machines. You should create a self-hosted agent on the same machine where the FDK is installed.

And then you need configure your pipeline to run on this self-hosted agent by targeting the pipeline agent pool to your local agent pool. So that your pipeline will be able to access to the FDK installed on the local machine while running on the self-hosted agent.

See the detailed steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) to create self-hosted agent.

Comment: Hi, I have managed to get hold of the files and mapping them, I used the Azure FIile copy. I now get this error "Error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'fapi.h': No such file or directory"

Comment: Hi Can you share your pipeline? Make sure the file fapi.h exists in the path you set up in the task.

Comment: I cannot share the pipeline. However, I am copying the files all that are available in the FDK directory that I use in my local system. I have copied this file in my TFS repository, then I created a copy file task which copies the files from the repository to the working directory of the build. I checked path where the files are copied and and the working directory if they are same, and they do match. I have also checked if that particular file gets copied and it does get copied.